# Replacing numpy.fft routines with pyfftw, not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy, fft, fftw, pyfftw

I have some working python code making use of the numpy.fft package, here is a snippet:

```
for i in range(steps):
    print i
    psixvec = Ux * psixvec
    psikvec = Uk * np.fft.fftn(psixvec)
    psixvec = np.fft.ifftn(psikvec)

return psixvec
```

I tried to rewrite this code to make use of the `pyfftw` package. What I came up with is the following code, which *should* work:

```
fft = fftw.builders.fftn(psix_align, auto_align_input = True, auto_contiguous = True,
                      overwrite_input = False, threads = 1, avoid_copy = False)

ifft = fftw.builders.ifftn(psik_align, auto_align_input = True, auto_contiguous = True,
                      overwrite_input = False, threads = 1, avoid_copy = False) 


for i in range(steps):
    psix_align[:] = Ux * psix_align
    psik_align[:] = Uk * fft()
    psix_align[:] = ifft()

return psix_align
```

The problem is, this code does not produce the same result as using the `numpy.fft` package. See the attached images.

[image: numpy fft package]
[image: pyfftw package]

Comment: Which image is the result of which computation?

Comment: First image is numpy, second is pyfftw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. For the initialization I was using

```
psix_align = fftw.n_byte_align(psi0, fftw.simd_alignment, dtype='complex64')
psik_align = fftw.n_byte_align(np.zeros_like(psi0), fftw.simd_alignment, dtype='complex64')
```

I needed to replace `complex64` with `complex128`. Now I get the same result. That's probably due to the fact that the numbers involved are very small (see the `1e-11` on the z-axis).

Edit: Maybe someone can add `pyfftw` to the tags of the question?